# xna how to use a bitmap from photoChooser?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

hi
i got a bitmapImage from the optionMenuScreen and want to use it in the GamePlayScreen.
do i have to convert it to texture2d?
how? example please...
in what class?
how can i change the bitmap size or change it after its a texture?
thanks

Comment: and how to get the system.drawing class?

Answer (score 1):

As `PhotoResult.ChosenPhoto` is a stream, I'd try using `Texture2D.FromStream` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434103.aspx))

System.Drawing is not supported on the phone.

Comment: but thats a static method so you can't do alot with it. or do you or doyou have some other ideas?

Comment: What does this comment mean Goote? If you have a stream that contains a valid PNG or JPG you can load it as a Texture2D with FromStream.

Comment: ok got it but how do i initialize the graphicsDevice device? void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult result) { if (result.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK) { bmp = new BitmapImage(); bmp.SetSource(result.ChosenPhoto); photoRecieved =Texture2D.FromStream( device, result.ChosenPhoto); } }

Comment: You must have a graphics device created somewhere right? Otherwise how can you render anything.

Comment: ok got it : photoRecieved =Texture2D.FromStream(ScreenManager.GraphicsDevice , result.ChosenPhoto);                now, when i'm trying to get the photo in the gamePlayScreen after pressing the back button, its null again. do i have to go straight to the next screen without back button or do you have another solution? thanks alot